# Angular unit test - how to test reactive form reset method?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, jasmine

I'm trying to test this method:

```
doResetForm(){
   this.form.reset();
}
```

so I tried:

```
it('should reset the form', () => {
   const spyformReset = jest.spyOn(component.form, 'reset');
   
   fixture.detectChanges();
   component.doResetForm();
   expect(spyformReset).toHaveBeenCalled();
}
```

but I'm getting the error:

> Cannot spyon on a primitive value, undefined give

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **spyOn** to mock the method.

```
const spyformReset = spyOn(component.form, 'reset').and.callThrough();
component.doResetForm();
expect(spyformReset).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: This didn't work for me